# Cannot find module './messages/embed/Assertions'

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot that is running on for a couple weeks on heroku. I didn't have any issues untill i tried to add slash commands. When i try to run it locally everything is working. But when i deploy the bot on Heroku i get the following error.

[image: error log]

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "discrsbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Discord bot for rs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "run index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/*****"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/*****"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/*****",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.7.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.1.0-canary.0",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.4",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.20.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.1.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "7.24.1"
  }
}
```

add.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');
const { groupID, groupKey } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('add')
        .setDescription('Add a player to TempleOSRS')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('rsn')
            .setDescription('RSN of the player u want to add to TempleOSRS')
            .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const rsn = interaction.options.getString('rsn');
        try {
            fetch(`https://templeosrs.com/api/add_group_member.php?`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                body: `id=${groupID}&key=${groupKey}&players=${rsn}`
            })
            .then(interaction.reply(`**${rsn}**, Has been added to the TempleOSRS group!`))
        } catch (error) {
            interaction.reply('Oops, there was an error fetching the API');
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
};
```

All modules seem to be installed/up-to-date on Heroku.

Is anyone able to help me out? Because i have no idea where the problem is comming from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us your `add.js` file?

Comment: included it now

Comment: This seems like a Discord.js issue. Make sure you've updated to the **latest** Discord.js version or at least v13. And ensure you're using node v16+

Comment: my node version is 16.13 and the discord version is 13.1

Comment: It actually appears to be an issue with `@discordjs/builders`, according to your error. Try using the latest version of that. It was updated to v0.8.2 yesterday. Let us know if it is still not working.

Comment: Yep that was the issue, it's working now. Thanks for the help